# Is there a data object that is not a variable or a constant?

Tags: c, data-objects

I am a student studying programming. 
I'm studying programming linguistics, and I'm asking for help because there's a part that doesn't work out well while solving the problem.

The problems are as follows:

For an elemental data type in a language with which you are familiar, do the following:

A. ...

B. Show a situation during execution where a data object of that type exists that is neither a variable nor a constant.

C. ...

The part I don't understand here is question number B. According to the textbook, data objects are variables or constants, and constants can be classified as literal and named constants, but data objects that are neither variables nor constants can be found. I'd appreciate your help.

I was solving the problem by setting the language that I am familiar with as C language.

Comment: The text of B doesn't make sense, or at least uses odd terms. What is a "situational painting innovation"? What does it mean for an object to "exponent that is possible or a constant"?

Comment: I think if you want an answer to the question "is there a data object in C that is not a variable or a constant" then you have to define specifically what you mean by "data object", "variable", and "constant".

Comment: Um... I'm sorry. I thought programmers would know this because it's something they learn from programming languages, but I guess what they learn here is not essential. Data object means the memory space that contains the data and can be taken as a variable. I don't think it's the exact same meaning as the variable.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't see anything wrong in the process of moving the problem, so I wrote it down. I just fixed the problem.

Comment: Constant and variable are compile-time constructs, but "data object" sounds like a run-time construct. C doesn't have one single notion of "constant" -- it has preprocessor things like `#define K 42` which you might call a constant, it has variables annotated with `const`, it has literals like `42`, it has literal strings for which it's undefined behavior to modify. That's why I asked for a specific definition of how you're using these terms. [note, I have a PhD in the field of programming language semantics]

Comment: Maybe the answer to your question is as simple as `int a[1] = {0}; printf("%d", a[0]);` Here `a[0]` is not a variable (depending how you define variable) or a constant, but refers to "data".

Comment: First of all, I'm sorry if I offended you when I said I thought programmers would know. I didn't mean to. And thank you for your comments. But what you wrote as an example seems really simple, but I don't understand it well because I don't know it well. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Not sure I understood your question...*

Here are two unnamed objects

```
struct Foo { int bar; double quux; }
(struct Foo){42, 3.14159}

(int)42
```

you can use them through a pointer

```
struct Foo *foo = &((struct Foo){42, 3.14159});
foo->quux = 2.71828;

int *fooi = &((int){42});
*fooi = -1;
```

you can use them as function parameters

```
foofx((struct Foo){42, 3.14159});
foon((int){42});
```

---

https://ideone.com/ibhdYq <== with (struct Foo)
https://ideone.com/XB1bkO <== with (int)